# Set TextField and PickerView In UIAlertView

Tags: swift3, xcode8.2

I want to create an alert with textfield and picker view. 
I want that at top show picker view first and then textfield below picker view.

[image]

Here is my code

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create Meditation", message: "myMsg", preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.view.addSubview(pickerView)

alert.addTextField { (textField) in
textField.text = "Enter Message"

}


let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .default) { (action) in
    let textField = alert.textFields

    print(textField)

            }
let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(action)
alert.addAction(action2)

let height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.50)
    alert.view.addConstraint(height);

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a uiviewcontroller and give it this effect.

For example: In the next image, i created a view as modal. it is a uiviewcontroller with a gray view (In your case, in the gray view you should put the uitextfield and uipickerview). Then, i configure storyboard segue as present modally and to give the effect of the modal in the uiviewcontroller put:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code :

```
 let alertView = UIAlertController(
            title: "Select",
            message: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
            preferredStyle: .alert)

        let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame:
            CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 260, height: 162))
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        alertView.view.addSubview(pickerView)
        alertView.addTextField(configurationHandler: configurationTextField)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:nil))
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
            guard let text = self.textField?.text else {return}
            print(text)
        }))
        present(alertView, animated: true, completion: {
            pickerView.frame.size.width = alertView.view.frame.size.width
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `UIAlertController` for that, as it doesn't have an option to add views other than textfields.
So, you have to write your own control, that will mimic `UIAlertController`.
You can write view controller and present it modally, or create a view and add it to the controller view.
Also, could be good idea to try to find ready component on [github.com](http://github.com) or [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com) and modify it as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

try these Pods hope it helps you

https://github.com/nealyoung/NYAlertViewController